# How to Get the Id Attribute of an Input Control in a Blazor Component

Tags: c#, blazor

Please, I am trying to get the id of an input control 'txtCounter' in a Blazor component using my C# codes. How do I access the value of the Id attribute i.e. 'txtCounter' in this case, of a blazor component using my C# code in an ASP.NET Core Blazor component. Below is the code I am using.

[image of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SbY8.jpg)

Thanks, as I look forward to getting your responses.

Comment: What do you need the id for?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<input type="text" id="@CounterInputId" value="@currentCount" />

@code {
    private const string CounterInputId = "txtCounter";

    private int currentCount = 0;
    ...
}
```

and now you have the id of the input element in your C# code.